# Ajax show error on php json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from a json array that is populated by a php file. The data passes successfully to the php file, but it returns errors. I tried to inspect the page, it shows the returned arrays in the network element as shown in the picture [Network inspection element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMZ4s.jpg), but the ajax success function won't work. If the data were passed successfully from the php file, why isn't execute the ajax successful function?
This is my ajax code:

```
var a = $(this).attr('idq');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "try.php",
    data: {
     queryy: a
    },

    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {

     var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
     $.each(data, function(index, value) {
         alert("successful");
     });

    },

    error: function(result) {
     alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Remove `dataType:"json"` property and see if you get the result back in success since you are parsing the object in success call back function ,

Comment: Did you read the errors?

Comment: I tried that and still doesn't show successful

Comment: it reads the error as [object Object]

Comment: That isn't an error.  Use the debugger or `console.log` to find out what it actually is.

Comment: Is it possible this sentence `queryy: a` is causing you problems?

Comment: But it actually passes successfully to the php file. And the php file reads POST queryy.

Comment: do you send the json headers from php? `header('Content-Type: application/json')`, do it **before** the **echo** or **print** sentences that could submit your response to ajax.

Comment: Yes, and it's before echo  array

Answer (score 1):

If you give the `dataType` as `json`, then no need for `parseJSON`. Just remove the `jQuery.parseJSON()` from your code.

Comment: I deleted it, and still showing error [object Object].

Comment: Dont use alert(). Try `console.log(result);`. You can find the result in the browser console panel.

Comment: Open your browser inspect element and go to network section. You can monitor you Ajax request and response from there.

Answer (score 0):

`dataType:"json"` tells jQuery to parse the response as JSON.

Therefore, you're passing an actual object to `jQuery.parseJSON`, which won't work